# How to raise HTTPError

Tags: python, urllib2

To test some code which uses [**`urllib2`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), I want to raise an [**`HTTPError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPError) to make sure it is handled correctly.

`HTTPError` has a constructor:

```
def __init__(self, url, code, msg, hdrs, fp):
```

I don't know what to pass as the last argument `fp`.

Can you help me with an example that will raise an `HTTPError` e.g. 
`raise HTTPError('arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4',...`

How can it be done?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's used by `urllib2`.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm going to handle the case when the HTTPError would occur, so first I must provoke it. When I've written the functionality that will handle the error, then I'm going to remove this code that provokes the error to happen.

Comment: For testing purposes it would be good to keep some code or data which causes the error.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes it should have a test that does this. What we did was rendering an error message ("Data could not be fetched") and we needed to generate the case that should not occur. I'm going to write a test for the error message that raises the HTTPError now that we could style the error message red and centered on the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `fp=None`.

From the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/41021c771510/Lib/urllib2.py#l187):

> ```
> # The addinfourl classes depend on fp being a valid file
> # object.  In some cases, the HTTPError may not have a valid
> # file object.  If this happens, the simplest workaround is to
> # not initialize the base classes.
> if fp is not None:
>     self.__super_init(fp, hdrs, url, code)
> ```

`fp` needs to be a file-like object, so you could pass a [**`StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object if you liked.